# Oracle Table Variables

Tags: oracle, plsql

Using Oracle PL/SQL is there a simple equivalent of the following set of T-SQL statements?  It seems that everything I am finding is either hopelessly outdated or populates a table data type with no explanation on how to use the result other than writing values to stdout.

```
declare @tempSites table (siteid int) 

insert into @tempSites select siteid from site where state = 'TX'

if 10 > (select COUNT(*) from @tempSites)
begin 
    insert into @tempSites select siteid from site where state = 'OK'
end

select * from @tempSites ts inner join site on site.siteId = ts.siteId
```

As @AlexPoole points out in his comment, this is a fairly contrived example. 
What I am attempting to do is get all sites that meet a certain set of criteria, and if there are not enough matches, then I am looking to use a different set of criteria.

Comment: It might be useful to explain the logic if what you are trying to do, as this appears a bit of a contrived situation. Incidentally, is the `<` the right operator, or should it be `>`? You seem to want all columns from your site table where the state is TX, and if there are more than 10 of those, then also all those where the state is OK?

Comment: Updated.  Example is a shortened and modifed version of what is actually being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle doesn't have local temporary tables, and global temporary tables don't look appropriate here.

You could use a common table expression ([subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF30048)):

```
with tempSites (siteId) as (
  select siteid
  from site
  where state = 'TX'
  union all
  select siteid
  from site
  where state = 'OK'
  and (select count(*) from site where state = 'TX') < 10
)
select s.*
from tempSites ts
join site s on s.siteid = ts.siteid;
```

That isn't quite the same thing, but gets all the TX IDs, and only includes the OK ones if the count of TX ones - which has to be repeated - is less than 10. The CTE is then joined back to the original table, which all seems a bit wasteful; you're hitting the same table three times.

You could use a subquery directly in a filter instead:

```
select *
from site
where state = 'TX'
or (state = 'OK'
  and (select count(*) from site where state = 'TX') < 10);
```

but again the TX sites have to be retrieved (or at least counted) a second time.

You can do this with a single hit of the table using an inline view (or CTE if you prefer) with an analytic count - which add the count of TX rows to the columns in the actual table, so you'd probably want to exclude that dummy column from the final result set (but using `*` is bad practice anyway):

```
select *    -- but list columns, excluding tx_count
from (
  select s.*,
    count(case when state = 'TX' then state end) over (partition by null) as tx_count
  from site s
  where s.state in ('TX', 'OK')
)
where state = 'TX'
or (state = 'OK' and tx_count < 10);
```

From your description of your research it sounds like what you've been looking at involved PL/SQL code populating a collection, which you could still do, but it's probably overkill unless your real situation is much more complicated.